# Low-level time series driver for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, driver, time-series

Oracle has OTS (Oracle Time Series) oriented tables. This produces lightning-fast queries for data that is naturally ordered by time, e.g. QOS telemetry data.

I've heard of a company that has produced an equivalent plugin for SQL Server 2008 that replaces the low-level database driver with its own, high-performance time-series version. Does anybody know the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have been mistaken, there seems to be no such company.